# Euclid vs Eratosthenes

Tags: ho.history-overview

Very little is known about Euclid's life--much less than about other famous ancient Greek mathematicians, which is puzzling. It is also strange to me that Euclid didn't write about the Eratosthenes sieve.

Thus I'd like to ask mathematical historians and everybody else: is there any clear proof that Euclid and Eratosthenes are two different people?

---

I wonder if Euclid's Elements were considered by the top geometers of Archimedes times (before and afterward for awhile) as teaching materials (or even philosophical too) rather than mathematical research. Especially that Elements were not mentioned much in those years, they became popular quite a bit later.

---

For a longer time, even after Archimedes, **nobody** talked about Euclid of Alexandria. Instead, they talked only  about "*the author of Elements*". Possibly, the geometric part of *Elements* was a cumulation of the work by several mathematicians, of which Eudoxes was a big part. But the number theoretical part of Elements and the Eratosthenes Sieve were perhaps by the same author, namely Erathostenes.

---

The *Elements* had no name nor any pseudonym assigned to it. That's why nobody was talking explicitly about the author.

Bourbaki used to have meetings together in a single room (perhaps a different room at the different occasions). They have established common notation and conventions, etc. Thus their textbooks had a fairly consistent style. They used to write in that style also monographs by single Bourbakist authors. In the case of the ancient authores such consistency was impossible due to the time and space span. This is why I conjecture that Eratosthenes combined the past results by several authors (especially by Eudoxes) and Eratosthenes rewritten these results in his own hand. This would explain why there was no author mentioned but the style of *Elements* was consistent.

Comment: You mean you are surprised Euclid didn't discover the sieve before Eratosthenes?

Comment: @AHusain, indeed, it seems to me that it'd be very natural for Euclid to discover the Eratosthenes Sieve.

Comment: In general, Eratosthenes' life seems to be much better documented than Euclid's. It would be quite strange if it was just never mentioned that he also wrote the Elements. Assuming that he wrote them under the pseudonym of Euclid (unnoticed by either Strabo or the byzantine Suba) seems to be a little far-fetched. In particular because, as Mikhail Katz mentioned, it seems likely that the Elements were written before (or very early in) Erathostenes' lifetime.

Comment: I have voted to close this.  History questions could well be appropriate here, but it's unclear to me what the reason is for believing that Euclid and Eratosthenes are the same.  Maybe in 2000 years someone might think that Weyl, Weil and Wiles were all the same mathematician -- after all, in the distant future it might seem incomprehensible why one of them couldn't as well have proved what the others did.

Comment: There was some arguing about whether a recent edit is editorializing, that I removed as it was getting a bit heated, and I think the edit can be read more as clarifying what the question is about (in particular, that Eratosthenes might be just *one* of the authors, particularly regarding books dealing with arithmetic, not geometry). I do think the question is interesting or at least fair, but also that it is undoubtedly never going to be answered definitively (unless some buried papyri come to light, Nag Hammadi-like). In keeping with long-standing precedent in such matters, I've made it CW.

Comment: It seems worthwhile to record at least a reference to the standard view: http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Euclid.html .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C.K. Raju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._K._Raju) goes to some length to argue that Euclid did not exist at all, in [Good-Bye Euclid!](http://ckraju.net/papers/MathEducation1Euclid.pdf)

He starts from the established fact that, while Euclid was first mentioned by the 5th century philosopher [Proclus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proclus), our sources for Proclus are a translation from Arabic made in Toledo around the year 1000. Raju has a [political agenda](http://www.vikasinterventions.in/c-k-raju-abstract) for wishing to debunk Euclid, to which I do not subscribe, but some of his arguments are intriguing:

> Possibly, the name "Euclid" was inspired by a translation error made
>   at Toledo regarding the term *uclides* which has been rendered by some
>   Arabic authors as *ucli* (key) + *des* (direction, space). So,
>   *uclides*, meaning “the key to geometry”, was possibly misinterpreted as a Greek name *Euclides*.

.

> In attributing the Elements to an early Greek called Euclid, we are
>   supposing that there was a fixed text which was repeatedly copied out
>   without any significant change by subsequent scribes. But the
>   available papyri on geometry from Alexandria do not correspond to the
>   received text, and do not show any such evidence of the existence of a
>   fixed, early text.

---

Mikhail Katz pointed me, via a [MSE thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841508/have-historians-of-the-classical-period-responded-to-c-k-rajus-critique), to a [review](https://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/3/378.extract) by José Ferreirós on Raju's [book](http://ckraju.net/books/Sandhan-review-Cultural-Foundations-of-Mathematics.pdf), since it's behind a paywall I quote the relevant paragraph:

> In his interest to revise traditional historiography and oppose
>   proof-centred mathematics, Raju devotes a lot of effort to questioning
>   the existence of Euclid and insisting that the text of the Elements
>   originates at the earliest in 370 CE (with Theon) or perhaps even in
>   the tenth century. In my opinion, this is useless and does not help
>   advance the author’s main theses. For historical purposes, what is
>   relevant is that Elements represents a systematisation of a large
>   portion of geometrical knowledge in the Greek-speaking world before
>   the common era. (‘Euclid’ is simply the name of its otherwise unknown
>   author, whose dates—it is true—are dubious; incidentally, an
>   interesting question would be whether philologists find reason to
>   think that the text of Elements was written by different authors.)
>   Raju insists on the idea that Proclus’s views represent the original
>   philosophy of mathematics in the Elements (p. 25), and he
>   overemphasizes the connections between geometrical proof, Platonism,
>   and Christian religion (see below).

Comment: This article seems to be unpublished. Is C. K. Raju a reputable scholar?

Comment: Apparently, a longer version of this text is published in: C. K. Raju, Cultural Foundations of Mathematics, Pearson Longman, New Delhi 2007. (Project of History of Indian Science, Philosophy and Culture, vol X, part 4.)

Comment: Are you aware of any scholarly reviews of that?

Comment: You mention a "political agenda" in the current form of your answer. Is there any reason to think this would not be present in his Indian publisher?

Comment: I don't at all see how this definitively answers the question, "is there any clear proof that Euclid and Eratosthenes are two different people?"  If the question were "did Euclid actually exist?", then this answer might be an interesting data point, but the question seems to be about a stronger claim, that the author of The Elements might have been Eratosthenes, which this answer doesn't touch. (Please note that I am not criticizing Carlo Beenakker for this answer; I am criticizing acceptance of his response as a *definitive* answer.)

Comment: Mauro pointed out at MSE that there is a review of the book by Ferreiros [here](https://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/3/378.extract).

Comment: @Carlo, you might want to reproduce also the sentence immediately preceding the one you quoted :-)

Comment: See related thread [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841508).

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I don't know much about the formal aspects of OM. Thus, because of this and due to the hostile attitude of some of the participants of this thread, I felt that I better accept the otherwise excellent answer by Carlo before the thread gets closed/removed, even if Carlo's answer was not definite.

Answer (score 9):

[Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) lived around -200 (more precisely -276 to -195/194) and was a correspondent of Archimedes.  Archimedes communicated his *Method* to Eratosthenes in the form of a [letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Method_of_Mechanical_Theorems). Euclid lived around -300.  He would have had to enjoy extraordinary longevity to coincide with Eratosthenes.

Comment: I like your notation for dates!

Comment: @MikhailKatz, I feel that you didn't even try to check the facts or what is believed by history.

Comment: That's possible. Which of the dates do you wish to challenge? If you feel that the traditionally cited dates are incorrect you should discuss this explicitly in your *question*.

Comment: From en.wikipedia:

*- Around 255 BC, he invented the armillary sphere.*
*- librarian at the Library of Alexandria in the year 245 BC.*

Comment: Yes but this still puts him at a distance of 50 years from Euclid.

Comment: Less than 50. But first of all, it is not clear that there was any "*Euclid of Alexandria*" at all.

Comment: So your theory is that Eratosthenes wrote *The Elements*? This might be an interesting theory but perhaps more appropriate to the history of science and mathematics site HSM.

Comment: It should be mentioned that we do not know the year of birth of Erathosthenes precisely. As the footnote to the year of birth at wikipedia mentions, we only know that an encyclopedia written more than 1000 years after Erathosthenes says that his year of birth was between 276 and 272 BC, but Strabo writes something that suggests he might have been born earlier. The dates of Euclid are of course even backed by less evidence. But I agree that it seems unlikely by the dates we know that Eratosthenes wrote the elements.

Comment: Your date notation is somewhat confusing, since there is no year 0. Does "$n$ BCE" correspond to $-n$ or $-(n-1)$?

Comment: @Argon --- I would imagine Mikhail Katz is referring to the [astronomical year numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering) -- where year 0 is the Julian year 1 BC; so $n$ BC/BCE is $-(n-1)$